# Advanced text search and importing specific strings to VB from file

Tags: vb.net, file, search, text

I will start off by saying this is my first post to VBForums, I have been lurking for some time. I am fairly new to VB and am only learning it to complete my Thesis. So please excuse my ignoarnace.

What I am trying to do, is read data from a log file generated by another program. I need a specific line from that file to be taken into VB for use in other algorithms. This log file will be constantly updating so it needs to be a live read if possible.

If it matters, the log file is being generated from a USB device communicating with another piece of software.

Here is a sample log:

```
`
08:57:00.932    COM12
08:57:00.935    COM11
08:57:00.935    COM10
08:57:00.936    COM9
08:57:00.936    COM8
08:57:00.937    COM7
08:57:00.938    COM6
08:57:00.939    COM5
08:57:00.939    COM4
08:57:00.998    --> 0108000304FF0000
08:57:01.007    <-- 0108000304FF0000

TRF7970A EVM 


08:57:01.014    **** COM Port found! ****
08:57:05.009    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:05.009    COM4
08:57:05.173    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:05.173    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:05.280    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:05.280    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:05.715    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:05.716    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:05.822    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:05.822    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:05.929    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:05.929    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:06.364    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:06.365    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:06.470    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:06.470    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:06.576    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:06.576    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:07.011    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:07.012    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:07.117    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:07.117    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:07.223    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:07.223    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:07.658    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:07.659    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:07.764    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:07.764    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:07.870    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:07.870    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:08.305    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:08.306    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:08.411    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:08.411    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:08.517    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:08.517    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:08.952    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:08.952    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:09.058    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:09.058    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:09.164    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:09.164    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:09.585    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]

[AD87851A000007E0,7F]

[,40][,40]D
08:57:09.586    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:09.692    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:09.692    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:09.798    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.


08:57:09.798    --> 010B000304140601000000
08:57:10.233    <-- 010B000304140601000000

ISO 15693 Inventory request.

[,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40][,40]D
08:57:10.234    --> 010A0003041001210000
08:57:10.340    <-- 010A0003041001210000

Register write request.


08:57:10.340    --> 010C00030410002101020000
08:57:10.446    <-- 010C00030410002101020000

Register write request.

`
```

I need to be able to get the line:
[AD87851A000007E0,7F]

to just "AD87851A000007E0" and then be able to use that string in VB. This is a hexadecimal code that will change.

I have been able to read from the log file, but not produce a valid output.

Here is the code I have been trying to use:

```
Function ReadData(ByRef keyword As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)
    Using reader = New StreamReader("C:\rfid-reader.log")
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        Dim take = False
        Do While line IsNot Nothing
            If line.StartsWith("[") Then
                take = False
            End If
            If String.Equals("[" + keyword + ",", line) Then
                take = True
            End If
            If take And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) And Not line.StartsWith("'") Then
                result.Add(line)
            End If
            line = reader.ReadLine()
    Label1.Text = line
        Loop
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

To be honest, I am not sure if the code is not working or if I am just doing something wrong with regards to getting the string out of the function? Will the function print to Label1.Text as it is?

I have also tried calling the function like this:

```
Dim items = ReadData("AD87851A000007E0")

Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(items)
```

This results in Label1.Text becoming "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

---

### EDIT 1

```
Imports System.IO
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim items = ReadData("AD87851A000007E0")

    Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items)


End Sub

Function ReadData(ByRef keyword As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)
    Using reader = New StreamReader("C:\rfid-reader.log")
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        Dim take = False
        Do While line IsNot Nothing

            take = False ' resetting take = false to avoide printing all lines

            If line.StartsWith("[" + keyword + ",") Then
                take = True
            End If

            If take And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) And Not line.StartsWith("'") Then
                result.Add(line)
            End If
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

End Class

EDIT 2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

New code to date:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim items = ReadData("AD87851A000007E0")  ' Calling the specific hex code from the function. Advancement needed to get ALL hex codes.

    '   Dim items1 As String = Convert.ToString(items)
    '   Dim items2 As String = ""


    '   Dim k As Long
    '   k = InStrRev(items, ",")
    '   If k > 0 Then items2 = Left$(items, k)

    Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items)  'Printing function result to Label1


End Sub


'Function to search log file for a specific hex code. Removes not needed portions of the string. Advancements needed: 
'Find ALL hex codes
'Ignore repeats until a reset is set true
'Store each hex code found in it's own variable for use in algorithms


Function ReadData(ByRef keyword As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)
    Using reader = New StreamReader("C:\rfid-reader.log")
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        Dim take = False

        Do While line IsNot Nothing
            take = False ' resetting take = false to avoide printing all lines

            If line.StartsWith("[" + keyword + ",") Then
                take = True
            End If


            If take And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) And Not line.StartsWith("'") Then
                line = line.Remove(0, 1) 'removing the extra parts of the line
                line = line.Remove(16, 4)
                result.Add(line) 'adding the valid result

            End If
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

End Class

---

### EDIT 3

```
Imports System.IO
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim items = ReadData("[")  ' Calling the specific hex code from the function. Advancement needed to get ALL hex codes.

    Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items)  'Printing function result to Label1


End Sub


'Function to search log file for a specific hex code. Removes not needed portions of the string. Advancements needed: 
'Find ALL hex codes
'Ignore repeats until a reset is set true
'Store each hex code found in it's own variable for use in algorithms


Function ReadData(ByRef keyword As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)
    Using reader = New StreamReader("C:\rfid-reader.log")
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        Dim line1 As String = "COOKIES"
        Dim line2 As String = "COOKIES1"
        Dim line3 As String = "COOKIES2"
        Dim line4 As String = "COOKIES3"
        Dim line5 As String = "COOKIES4"
        Dim line6 As String = "COOKIES5"
        Dim line7 As String = "COOKIES6"
        Dim line8 As String = "COOKIES7"
        Dim line1found = False
        Dim line2found = False
        Dim line3found = False
        Dim line4found = False
        Dim line5found = False
        Dim line6found = False
        Dim line7found = False
        Dim line8found = False
        Dim take = False

        Do While line IsNot Nothing

            take = False ' resetting take = false to avoide printing all lines

            If line.StartsWith(keyword) And Not line.StartsWith("[,4") And Not line.StartsWith("[z,") Then
                take = True
            End If

            If line.Contains(line1) Or line.Contains(line2) Or line.Contains(line3) Or line.Contains(line4) Or line.Contains(line5) Or line.Contains(line6) Or line.Contains(line7) Or line.Contains(line8) Then  'attempting to ignore duplicates
                take = False
            End If

            If take And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) And Not line.StartsWith("'") Then
                line = line.Remove(0, 1) 'removing the extra parts of the line
                line = line.Remove(16, 4)
                result.Add(line) 'adding the valid result

                If line1 <> line And Not line1found Then  'assining results to variables for duplicate elimiation
                    line1 = line
                    line1found = True

                ElseIf line2 <> line And line1 <> line And Not line2found Then
                    line2 = line
                    line2found = True

                ElseIf line <> line3 And line <> line2 And line1 <> line And Not line3found Then
                    line3 = line
                    line3found = True

                ElseIf line <> line4 And line <> line3 And line <> line2 And line <> line1 And Not line4found Then
                    line4 = line
                    line4found = True

                ElseIf line <> line5 And line <> line4 And line <> line3 And line <> line2 And line <> line1 And Not line5found Then
                    line5 = line
                    line5found = True

                ElseIf line6 <> line And line5 <> line And line4 <> line And line3 <> line And line2 <> line And line1 <> line And Not line6found Then
                    line6 = line
                    line6found = True

                ElseIf line7 <> line And line6 <> line And line5 <> line And line4 <> line And line3 <> line And line2 <> line And line1 <> line And Not line7found Then
                    line7 = line
                    line7found = True

                ElseIf line8 <> line And line7 <> line And line6 <> line And line5 <> line And line4 <> line And line3 <> line And line2 <> line And line1 <> line And Not line8found Then
                    line8 = line
                    line8found = True

                End If
            End If
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: There's a main thing that's confusing me about your spec.  You seem to be searching this log file for a given string.  Just one string, right?  This 'keyword' that you're passing into the function.  But you're also saying that you need to look for multiple unique hex codes.  I'm not grokking how those can both be true.  Also, if you're looking for this single string, why are you returning a collection of strings?  It looks to me like there is a fundamental algorithm-level misunderstanding that you need help on (first) rather than just some VB syntax.

Comment: Read below clweeks. That was an early stage of the code just getting it working with one. The idea was to find more than one. Which I have done now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.  The first problem is that you are using `String.Equals` instead of `line.StartsWith`:

```
If String.Equals("[" + keyword + ",", line) Then
    take = True
End If
```

You'll notice that in that above code, it will only set `take = True` if the entire line exactly matches the string "[AD87851A000007E0,".  But the line you are looking for doesn't equal that string--it merely begins with that string.  Therefore, you should change that code to this:

```
If line.StartsWith("[" + keyword + ",") Then
    take = True
End If
```

Next, you are setting the `Label1.Text = line` inside the loop after it reads each line, whether or not the line matches.  What you are doing will work, but probably not in the manner that you intend.  The way you have it right now, it overwrites the entire textual content of the label with each new line that is read.  As I said, it does so with every line, not just the matching ones.  Since you are busy in a loop, the screen won't actually refresh until you are done, so in the end, all it will do is display the last line in the file.

If you want it to display all matching lines, you need to move it to inside the `If take...` block, and you need to concatenate the lines together, like this:

```
If take And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) And Not line.StartsWith("'") Then
    result.Add(line)
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text & Environment.NewLine & line
End If
```

However, that's still not a great way to do that.  It's never a good idea to mix UI code in with your business logic, so your instinct to set the label after you call `ReadData` is the right idea.  However, you cannot use `Convert.ToString` to display the contents of a list.  As you found out, that will just display the name of the data type.  To do that, you'd need to join the strings in the list together into one string, like this:

```
Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items)
```

I used `Environment.NewLine` as the delimiter, but you can use whatever you want as the delimiter.  For instance, if you want to show them all on one line, you could use `", "` as the delimiter.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your reply! I have that part working now, see my code in EDIT 1.

Comment: Now I need to expand on it. I am working on the code now, but any insight will be quite helpful! 

As I said in the first post, that hexadecimal code I am looking for will change - so I need to be able to find them all without looking for the exact one.

Once I find a code, I need a loop to prevent it from being found a second time until a reset occurs. I need to be able to find multiple codes (up to 6 at a time) and store each in its own variable.

Comment: To help explain my goal, I will give a little more info on what it is I am trying to achieve:
I have a scanner working via USB and another piece of software that makes the log file. It scans unique tags and logs the ID number of each. I need to be able to scan multiple tags and then use the IDs in other algorithms to determine what each represents.

Thanks again for your help, this level of VB is new to me!

Comment: What data are you interested in?  Do you just need those hex codes, or do you also need the number that follows the comma?  If all you need is the hex code, then I would just store *that* in your `result` list.  If you need to store both values, then I would recommend storing the key/value pairs in a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`, or something, rather than a simple `List(Of String)`.  In either case, the point I'm making, is you want to store the specific data you care about, not the whole un-parsed line.  Then, it will be easier to detect repeats of the hex code and such.

Comment: From the line:
[AD87851A000007E0,77]

All I need is:
AD87851A000007E0

I need that to be stored in a variable, not found twice, and I need to be able to find multiple unique hex codes. Each stored in its own variable...

Comment: To store only unique values, you can simply check if the code is already in the list before adding the new one.  As far as getting just the Hex code from the line, I'd recommend stripping off the first character using the string's `SubString` method, then do a `Split(","c)` on the string and only take the first element from the array that returns.

Comment: Thanks for the help again Steven. I can now print the result in the format I want, see new update for new code. I am having some trouble finding a way to stop it from reading the same line twice. As you explained before, it does not update the screen until the loop is finished - so when I tell it to ignore a duplicate, it is ignoring the first copy as well!

Comment: Well, for starters, you need to stop passing the hex code into the method as a parameter and start finding all of them instead of just the one that is passed in.  To do that, you are going to need a whole different way of finding matches.  I would start by looking for lines that start with "[" and end with "]" and contain a comma.  Then, I'd remove the brackets and split on the comma.  Then I'd look to see if the element before the comma contains a value.  If so, I'd add it to the result list, but only if it doesn't already exist in the list.

Comment: More advancements! Got it finding multiple UIDs and only each one once. Now I need a way for it to clear each line in the log file after it's done - is there a simple way to do this? Looking around for it now. Thanks for all the help so far, making a lot of progress!

See new update for how I accomplished the goals.

Comment: How can that be working?  Are you populating the result list and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: @clweeks It's a bit confusing, but it's there... Yes, you missed it :)

Comment: There is no way to remove lines from a file, like that.  Blank them out by replacing them with white space, perhaps, but not removing them.  To remove text, and thereby push up the rest of the content of the file, you will need to write it out to a whole new file and then delete the old one.

Comment: Okay, so I have it finding multiple unique ID's now. I need a way to store each of those unique IDs in its own String. Having trouble finding a way that works to do this...

Comment: All of the strings are already stored in the list that is returned by the `ReadData` method, are they not?  If so, that's all you should need.  You can't really create multiple variables, one per hex code, unless you know precisely how many there will be.  If that doesn't answer your question, you will need to provide more details about how you intend to use these variables.

Comment: Hi again Steven. The number of hex codes I get back will vary, that's the problem I am having. I need them all to be in their own string. I need to perform operations on the hex codes outside of just finding them. Once I have each hex code in its own string I need to run them through multiple algorithms to determine what the represent. (For example: Each hex code is its own unique identification tied to some object. I need to determine which object(s) are found and what other object(s) should be found with it...)

Comment: When the number of strings is known, then it's easy... I just chop it up. But as soon as the code attempts to chop more than there is I get a run time error. Perhaps a method of finding the number of lines in the string then limiting the number of times it performs the split?

Comment: As far as I understood it, you got your `ReadData` method to return the list of hex codes where each item in the list was one hex code.  So, all you have to do is take that list that it returns and loop through the items in it, for instance: `For Each hexCode As String In items`.  Then, inside the loop, just process the current item via the `hexCode` iterator variable.

Comment: I agree.  When you have a list (or any collection) of strings (your hex codes) you already have each one in it's own string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but this is a modification of your Edit 3 to streamline several things and create a framework that allows you to extend the way you validate your lines:

```
Function readData() As List(Of String)
    readData = New List(Of String)
    Using reader As New StreamReader("C:\rfid-reader.log")
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            For Each line In reader.ReadToEnd.Split(ControlChars.CrLf)
                If validLine(line) AndAlso Not readData.Contains(line.Split(",")(0).Substring(1)) Then readData.Add(line.Split(",")(0).Substring(1))
            Next
        End While
    End Using
End Function

Private Function validLine(line As String) As Boolean
    validLine = True
    'insert criteria to validate the line's format (you could also look at regex)
    If Not line.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        validLine = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not line.Trim.StartsWith("[") AndAlso line.Trim.EndsWith("]") Then
        validLine = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not line.Split(",").Length = 2 Then
        validLine = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not line.Split(",")(0).Substring(1).Length > 1 Then
        validLine = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not isHex(line.Split(",")(0).Substring(1)) Then
        validLine = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    '...
End Function

Private Function isHex(str As String) As Boolean
    isHex = True
    For i = 0 To str.Length - 1
        If Not {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}.Contains(str.Substring(i, 1)) Then
            isHex = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the input clweeks. But there will be no further extension of strings. As I said in my first post - I am not very advanced with VB. I kept the code simple on purpose. Others have to be able to interpret it as well. I do agree this is much more streamlined - but not required at this stage. Thanks again for the input. Any input on the comments of the previous answer would be helpful.